# How do I edit MP4/H264 video files in Sony Vegas Platinum 6?

Tags: mp4, video-editing, h.264, sony-vegas

If I try to open an MP4 file made by a Sony Webbie in Sony Vegas Platinum 6, it won't open. (Something made me think they would work together.)

The Webbie files are H264. It will happily play MP4/H263.

Is there a codec or something I can download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to Sony Vegas 8. It can handle these files.

Answer (score 2):

You need encoder for vegas.

Try this - [x264 Encoder](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/x264_Encoder)

Comment: Yikes. SiteAdvisor.com lists that site as "yellow" and lists a load of software it has coming with Trojans.

Comment: Never had a problem with videohelp.com, but if you prefer here's a site with x264 builds that siteadvisor.com says is "clean": x264.nl